# Using a Cursor to Update Rows in Single Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, merge, cursor

I am seeking guidance using MS SQL cursor or SQL while loop to merge (add, update, and set inactive) rows using single table based on  criteria below resulting in seeking the final dataset:

---

TABLE VIEW (SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE ENTITY = 123 (@ID)

**ENTITY**    **ENTITY_TYPE**      **VALUE**           **STATUS_TYPE**

123          1                1               1
123          1                4               1
123          1                9               1

TABLE VIEW (SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE ENTITY = 456 (@OverrideID)

**ENTITY**    **ENTITY_TYPE**      **VALUE**           **STATUS_TYPE**
456          1                1              1
456          1                5              1

Final Data Set below:

**ENTITY**   **TYPE**       **VALUE**           **STATUS_TYPE**

123     1     1     3
123     1        4     3
123     1     9     3
456     1     1     1
456     1     4     1
456     1     9     1
456     1     1     1
456     1     5    1

-- Check and compare each row 
-- IF @OverrideID = @ID (MATCH) 
----- Set @ID to inactive keeping copy
-- If @OverrideID != @ID (NOT MATCH)
----- Insert @ID data with @OverrideID (COPY)
----- Set @ID to inactive.

I began writing the following and need help. For reference, @ID = 123 and @OverrideID = 456

---

```
DECLARE @ENTITY BIGINT, @ENTITY_TYPE BIGINT, @VALUE BIGINT, @E1 BIGINT, @T1 BIGINT, @V1 BIGINT
DECLARE type_cursor CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD FOR
SELECT * FROM TypeValue WHERE ENTITY = @ID

SET NOCOUNT OFF
OPEN type_cursor

FETCH NEXT FROM type_cursor INTO @OverrideID, @ID, @ENTITY, @ENTITY_TYPE, @VALUE

WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
    BEGIN

        SELECT @ENTITY, @ENTITY_TYPE, @VALUE

     IF @VALUE IS NOT NULL
        BEGIN
        SELECT @T1 = @ENTITY_TYPE, @V1 = @VALUE
        END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
    UPDATE TypeValue
    SET ENTITY = @OverrideID, ENTITY_TYPE = @T1, VALUE = @V1 WHERE ENTITY = @ID
    END

FETCH NEXT FROM type_cursor INTO @OverrideID, @ID, @ENTITY, @ENTITY_TYPE, @VALUE

END

CLOSE type_cursor 
DEALLOCATE type_cursor 
SET NOCOUNT OFF
```

Comment: In MS SQL I'd seriously start trying to think in result sets instead of using a cursor.

Comment: If you're not doing INSERTs how does your table balloon from 3+2 records to 8?

Answer (score 1):

That final result set looks like

```
    select entity,entity_type,value,3 status_type
      from [table]
     where entity = @id
 union all
    select @override,entity_type,value,status_type
      from [table]
     where entity = @id
 union all
    select entity,entity_type,value,status_type
      from [table]
     where entity = @override
```