# Ranking search results

Tags: mysql, sql, search

I have a tutoring website with a search feature. I want tutors to appear on the list according to several weighted criteria, including whether or not they are subscription holders, if they have submitted a profile photo, if they have included a lot of information about themselves, etc...

Basically, I have a lot of criteria by which I would like to weigh their rank.

Instead of writing a complicated SQL query with multiple ORDER BYs (if this is even possible), I was thinking of creating a table (maybe a temporary one), that assigns numerical values based on several criteria to come up with a final search rank.

I'm not entirely sure about how to go about this, or if this is a good idea, so I would like to know what the community thinks about a) this method, and b) possible ways of implementing this in SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would add a field to one of the existing tables that more or less was a representation of their "weight" for sorting purposes.  I would then populate this column with a database procedure that ran every so often (you could make a queue that only runs on records that have been updated, or just run it on all records if you want).  That way, I can just pull back the data and order by one column instead of multiple ones.

Also, you could use a View.  It really depends on if you want to number crunching to be done by the procedure or by the database every time you pull data (for a search feature and for speed's sake, I'd suggest the database procedure).

Comment: Hmm, so this "procedure" is a kind of stored procedure that I write right into MySQL (not my website's backend language (PHP)?). Sorry, I know that these things exist, but haven't written one before.

Comment: Right, its a stored procedure, set up with a scheduler job.  So the database runs it every so often.  It uses the database's resources, runs asynchronously with inserts/queries, so it is low impact for the user (unless it eats up so much of the database's resources that it slows it down that way, which would still be more efficient than doing it every query)

Comment: any recommendation for what kind of loop I should be using in my stored procedure to iterate through each user? I've read that 'cursor' is read only, so I wouldn't be able to update the table with that.

Comment: Look for examples online, you use the cursor to get the values you want to update, then use those values in the update statement.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12849883/using-a-cursor-to-update-rows-in-single-table

Comment: Fixed it up with a cursor loop -- must have misunderstood what 'read only' meant. Was able to put an UPDATE query inside the loop no problem.